# How to set the jdbc connection timeout value for remote connection to postgresql database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I created the application in Spring. I assume that the connection should be done in the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Once I host the application, the application stops connecting to the database, after a certain number of queries are hit to it. I looked it up and the probable reason could be that I did not  t set the connection timeout attribute. How can I do that?

Comment: The connection timeout is only there to abort a connection *attempt* if the database doesn't respond during that time. Once the connection is established the connection timeout does not play a role any more

Comment: Have you got errors ?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. After a certain number of queries, the front end simply doesn't connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like anything to do with connection timeouts. It's rather more likely that you are failing to release connections back to the connection pool after use, so you are "leaking" connections until you reach the pool's maximum concurrent connection limit.

I can't be more specific, as you haven't shown code, configuration, versions, log messages, or any other relevant detail. Review your code to verify you release connections back to the pool when you are done with them, or the framework you are using takes care of it for you.